# compile error when trying to parse to utree

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to parse a string to a utree using the following code:

```
void Parse(const std::string& testString, const MyGrammar<const char*>& parser)
{
    char const* first = testString.c_str();
    char const* last = &first[testString.size()];
    boost::spirit::utree tree;
    boost::spirit::qi::parse(first,last,parser,tree);
    std::cout << "tree: " << tree << '\n';
}
```

where MyGrammar is

```
namespace spirit  = boost::spirit;    

class MyGrammar : public spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, spirit::utree(), spirit::qi::space_type>
{
    ...
}
```

But this fails to compile with the following message:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'bool boost::function4::operator ()(T0,T1,T2,T3) const' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'const boost::spirit::unused_type' to 'const boost::spirit::qi::char_class ' c:\program files\etas\etasadlib\boost\1.49.0\include\boost\spirit\home\qi\nonterminal\rule.hpp  303 MyGrammarTest

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following post from sehe: [boost::qi::parse seems to cause compilation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389359/boostqiparse-seems-to-cause-compilation-errors) which answers this question: I need to use phrase_parse with a skipper

```
boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(first,last,parser, boost::spirit::qi::space,tree);
```